# Intellij does not open Scala files

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

[image][image: Intellij-Scala]

I'm using IntelliJ (version 13.0) and Scala (2.9.1).

I created a Test project but Intellij does not open/display the scala files in the editor window. It displays the files only when I select the option 'Mark as Plain text' from the context menu of the scala file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install a separate plugin for Scala support: [Scala plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=1347&_ga=1.249805254.1199310338.1404748527). This is also available directly from within IntelliJ IDEA using Preferences -> Plugins -> Jetbrains Plugins

More details about IDEA's Scala support are given here: [The Most Intelligent IDE for Scala Development](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/scala.html)

Next, you need to add the Scala SDK to IntelliJ IDEA, again using the Project Structure -> SDKs. Finally add the Scala Facet to your module using Project Structure -> Facets.

A step-by-step check-list is given here: [Getting Started with IntelliJ IDEA Scala Plugin](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/SCA/Getting+Started+with+IntelliJ+IDEA+Scala+Plugin). It's a bit out-of-date, but still covers all the steps.

Comment: Yes, I have already installed/enabled the Scala Plugin from Settings -> Plugins

Comment: Have you also installed the Scala SDK and added it into the project structure?

Comment: Yes, I have added a new image to make the project structure clear.

Comment: Hmm.. If you haven't already, try out the new link at the end of my answer. It's a setup guide for the Scala plugin.